# gwen + opengl can't see anything

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl

I'm trying to use GWEN to draw some GUI elements on top of my opengl scene. It seems to have set up correctly but nothing from gwen is actually being drawn (visibly at least). I'm using a custom renderer which is essentially GWEN's stock opengl renderer but with a different function for loading textures. And OpenGL::Begin() and OpenGL::End() replaced with these:

```
    void coRenderer::Begin()
    {
        glUseProgram(0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glDepthMask(0);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                // Select The Projection Matrix
        glPushMatrix();                             // Store The Projection Matrix
        glLoadIdentity();

        glOrtho(0, screen->w, screen->h, 0, -1, 1 );

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    }

    void coRenderer::End()
    {
        Flush();

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                // Select The Projection Matrix
        glPopMatrix();                              // Restore The Old Projection Matrix

        glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthMask(1);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

the code for gwen's opengl renderer is here:

http://gwen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/gwen/Renderers/OpenGL/OpenGL.cpp

BTW I'm using OpenGL 2.1 not 3.0+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah GWEN. That frustrating GUI library.

When I started using it, and integrating it into the engine we wrote in school, I had the same issue as you, using the stock OpenGL renderer however. Turned out it was being positioned wrong, calling glLoadIdentity() to reset the identity matrix seemed to resolve it.

The issue you are having, could well end up being the same as what I had, or there could be a problem with your custom OpenGL renderer. I'm not sure if you know much about GWEN, or how it works, but it runs on a single texture, that skins the GUI. Are you loading that in? Perhaps your texture loader isn't loading it correctly.

Try using your Debugger and stepping through your program. Areas of interest would be where you're attempting to load the GUI skin, where you're assigning the screen space that GWEN can use, and when you're actually attempting to render the GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I checked using gDebugger and the texture loads fine. I'll look into it further. Do you have any code that might help me?

Comment: @PgrAm As of right now I don't, since I haven't personally used GWEN much other than the initial attempt to get it working with the engine. Just check where abouts the GUI is being drawn, I suspect it's not a matter of it NOT drawing, it's a matter of WHERE it's drawing.